# Difference between "do good to" "do good for" and "do good by"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

What is the difference between “do good **to** others”, “do good **for** others” and “do good **by** others”?  They appear the same to my non-native ears. There must be subtle differences between them.

I only find “do…..by” and "do......to" in dictionaries.

> do by:
>
> To behave with respect to; deal with:
>
> https://www.thefreedictionary.com/do+by
>
> do something to someone:
>
> to treat someone in a way that harms them
>
> https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/do-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do good to others.

That means the others are directly receiving the good.

> Do good for others.

The others may not be directly receiving the good.

> Do good by others.

The others consider what you are doing to be good.  Some people not included in "the others" may not consider what you're doing to be good.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's important to distinguish that *doing good by <other(s)>* is judged by the notion of good to that third party, not necessarily generally being good. (So doing good by a thief might mean lying to the police, for instance, which isn't intrinsically a *for the greater good of all* action)

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard "to do good by" somebody.  "Do right by them" is a set phrase, but at least in the south-central US, I wouldn't say you can change the noun and still have a valid phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  You may find that some native speakers use these interchangeably.

Doing good **to** someone means that they are the *direct* recipient of the benefit of your action.  For example, if someone is hungry and you give them something to eat.

Doing good **for** someone means that they are an *indirect* recipient of the benefit of your action.  For example, if someone is hungry and you give money to a charity that provides food.

Doing good **by** somone means that their situation may be improved as a consequence of your actions (so your actions are guided by a respect for their situation).  For example, knowing that someone is hungry you resolve not to waste food or to campaign for restaurants to provide surplus food to a charity.

Answer (score 0):

Giving food to the hungry is doing good to someone and giving money to a charitable institution with the hope that your money will be of some help to the hungry is doing good for the hungry and giving up a bad habit of indecently wasting food keeping in view the plight of the hungry and needy is doing good by someone.

Comment: These are example sentences. I'm not sure they elucidate the differences very well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/136589)