# Can you "give good" to someone?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I wanted to thank someone who has helped me a lot, and I wanted to say that I hoped I could at some point "give back some of the good you've given me". But this doesn't sound correct. Is it ever grammatical to "give good" to someone? ([here's an ngram for "the good you have given"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+good+you+have+given+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20good%20you%20have%20given%3B%2Cc0))

I know someone can *do good to* someone else though, so would the above sentence be correct if I said instead "give back some of the good you've done to me"? It still sounds odd to my ears. How could I express this in proper English?

Related: [Difference between "do good to" "do good for" and "do good by"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/227169/difference-between-do-good-to-do-good-for-and-do-good-by)

Comment: There is a slang usage: "I gave it to him good!" but it means exactly the opposite of what you're intending!  It means that I angrily yelled at him or maybe even physically beat him up.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thanks for the heads-up!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> give back some of the good you've given me

No, this is not at all idiomatic.

The most idiomatic phrase to express this idea is "*return the kindness*", eg:

> "You were so kind to me, I would like to return the kindness".

You may also hear "return the *favour*", but some people may see a "favour" as a 'token' gesture and may prefer not to use that word.

Also, it is a bit unusual to say "*some of*" the kindness. When it comes to good or kind actions, reciprocation does not have to be like-for-like, but is not normally measured.

The only context in which you may hear "give good" is when 'good' is being used as a *grade* or *level* on a scale. For example, if a school teacher grades their children's work as either 'poor', 'average', 'good' or 'excellent', the teacher might say of a child "I gave them good" to mean they awarded them the 'good' level.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think "return/retribute the good you've done to me" could be any better?

Comment: @flen it's not as idiomatic as my suggestions. 'retribute' definitely not.